# What is this style of cupboard door called?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets

Trying to identify (and locate a replacement) for this style of kitchen cupboard door. I see them often, especially in rentals, here in Canada. I assume they are cheap, does this style, where a wooden lip spans the width of the door, have a name?

Are they a style from a specific manufacturer?

[image: cupboard door with white finish and wood lip that spans entire width]

Comment: look for a manufacturer name label

Answer (score 2):

While the "flush" or "[integrated handle](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&biw=1839&bih=979&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=u6hWXciVB4GasQW2sYuoDQ&q=integrated%20handle%20cabinet&oq=integrated%20handle%20cabinet&gs_l=img.3..0.2824.6606..6757...0.0..0.100.1734.24j1......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39j0i67j0i30j0i8i30j0i10i24.5wYHTy54vD4&ved=0ahUKEwiI34SBuYfkAhUBTawKHbbYAtUQ4dUDCAY&uact=5)" style door is common, it's likely that this particular design with this particular molding profile is proprietary. They were probably cheap to purchase initially due to economy of scale, but they may no longer be in production.

You may be better off refinishing the wood (sand, stain, seal), and if necessary reapply laminate to the face. Creating a new identical door would be an exercise in detail work.

Answer (score 1):

I actually did replicate one of these doors. Problem was that it was fiber board and swelled up. Luckily, it was covered with white laminate so I was able to build a new door and then refinished the wood strip and use it to finished it off. A fair amount of work but worth it. Plus, it gave me an excuse to buy a router table and some neat router bits.

Comment: @ isherwood First one down in the spelling bee

Answer (score 0):

I believe the more general name for this style is “overlay.” It may have a laminate or melamine surface, or it could be vinyl or vinyl coated.

You might be able to find one or have one custom made, but I’d bet having one made to match would be expensive. If your current doors have been installed for years the surfaces and wood have probably faded or changed color at least a little. Might be good if you need one to have one or more doors that are contrasting or complementary.